# Tableau Start, end, and center settings for colors in heat map

Tags: tableau-api

I think I have a simple question but I can't figure it out.

I have a measure that shows percentages. I want to use 'red-green-yellow diverging' under "edit colors" to set colors based on the following criteria:

```
0%-100% = green; 
100%-115% = yellow; 
greater than 115% = red
```

This should be so simple! I can't figure out how to use the "start", "end", "center" in the 'edit colors' to achieve what I want above.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  . if you want your question to be answered. Also consider reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking a question

Comment: If you're working with actual percentages, you want to set your values to things like `End: 1.15` and `Center: 1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write the if condition to achieve the result

```
if field >=0% and field <100% 
then green
elseif field >=100% and field <115% 
then yellow
else
red
```

Place formula in colors and then edit colors and then assign required colors for the output